# Discard null value in string[] java

Tags: java, android

I am taking some value by parsing the api and now i want to chek whether if through parsing the value comes null then the value should not be added to the string array and if there is some value then only should be added to the string[]. please help
This is my code:

```
String[] title_array=null;
myparseobj=new XMLParser();
if(myparseobj.xmlParsing(url,"item","title") != null){
    title_array=myparseobj.xmlParsing(url,"item","title");
}
```

But this is not working please help

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: not working means i used to get 4 values from the api the two with some specific values and the last two with null value so i want to check whether if the values are null then i dont want to insert into the string[] and if not null then only should add into the array and should display the length of the array accordingly

Answer (score 0):

`myparseobj=new XMLParser();` 
`String val = myparseobj.xmlParsing(url,"item","title");` 
`if(!((val == null)||("null".equalsIgnoreCase(val))){`

`title_array=myparseobj.xmlParsing(url,"item","title"); }`

Comment: do you mean to say that its still adding null values to the arraylist ?

Comment: ohh, u mean there are null values in title_array object ?, is it because you created this array to be a a fixed size earlier and now are populating certain values and the rest are being  null

Comment: yes exactly so what to do now ? see the above code i had just edited

Comment: or the best part would be use an arraylist add value to that and after the processing if you still need the array u can get as arraylist.toArray(). this will remove the empty value problem that you are reporting at the moment

Comment: Use ArrayList instead of Array. It will contains only the values which you will insert.

Comment: ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); add items using listItems.add(Obj);  finally convert back to array using listItems.toArray();

Comment: when i used this i got the only 1 as the size of the arraylist

Comment: declare the arraylist out of the loop and then see , i think u declared it within the loop and thats resetting every iteration of the loop

Comment: ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 String val = myparseobj.xmlParsing(url,"item","title").toString(); 
 listItems.add(val);
 System.out.println("value of listitemtitle::" +listItems.size());
 title_array =(String[])listItems.toArray();
 System.out.println("value of titlearray after conversion:" +title_array.length);

Comment: There is no loop and after running this code i am getting runtime exception

Comment: on the first point  if you dont hAve a loop why are you using an Array,could you edit the question with your whole method for better understanding

Comment: actually its the lazyadapter class which extends baseadapter so in the background i am parsing the value and storing it in the string[] and then displaying the values in the listview so for that i am getting two values as specific and two values null so i want to discard null values from the available values and want to display two items in the listview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9996/discussion-between-akash-yadav-and-user1266179)

Comment: Hi akash i solved the problem thnks for your help, Thanks a lot

Comment: yw, am sorry i couldnt reply as there was some problem with my internet connection